# Why does my java file not see the new elements in my R file?

Tags: java, android

I am creating a compound view.
I have created a class for my new view:

```
import android.R;
public class LogoAndTextButton extends LinearLayout{

public LogoAndTextButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setOrientation(VERTICAL);

    TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R. , 0, 0);
```

I have created a attrs.xml for the in my res/values:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <declare-styleable name="LogoAndTextButton">
        <attr name="image" format="reference"/>
        <attr name="text"  format="string"/>
    </declare-styleable> 
</resources>
```

the styleable shows up in my R.java file!!!

```
public static final class style {
    public static final int AppBaseTheme=0x7f080000;
    public static final int AppTheme=0x7f080001;
}
public static final class styleable {
    public static final int[] LogoAndTextButton = {
        0x7f010000, 0x7f010001
    };
    public static final int LogoAndTextButton_image = 0;

    public static final int LogoAndTextButton_text = 1;
};
```

but when I go to my LogoAndTextButton java class file and type "R." and cntrl+space, "styleable" does not show up as one of the elements. and if I type it manually it complains that it cant be resolved. I've tried cleaning my project, and closing and re opening eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is at the top of your source file

```
import android.R;
```

You are importing the Android resources, so it doesn't see yours. Remove that line and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I was importing android.R